# How to create an Admin layout and route views in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, layout, react-router, admin

I'm developing a web app using ReactJS. I want to create an Admin layout my self. My problem is, how to change the view without reloading the sidebar? I mean, there is a sidebar in the Admin layout. We have options to click there. When we click on a particular option, let's say "User Profile", it loads the User Profile page on the right side of the screen. The URL also changes. But, the sidebar does not reload. Please, someone, edit this if the thing I'm going to express is not much clear. I hope it is clear.

I want to know, how to do this? How to route the views like that?

Comment: you mean you need to reload the pages with or without the sidebar? I did not clearly understand the problem, provide some code, please

Comment: @Maria-Elena Yes. I want to load the pages but WITHOUT reloading the sidebar. That means, the sidebar does not reload, but the page reloads and URL changes as well. http://antillestores.fr/react-admin-demo/#/login You can check this example. Log into this example and you will see what I meant. Really appreciate if you can help me!

Comment: https://github.com/creativetimofficial/black-dashboard-react?ref=appseed

Comment: let me know if that works for you

Comment: @Maria-Elena Thanks for that. But, I want to implement it my self. What I don't understand is, how they implemented the routing.

Comment: Check this link please   https://codepen.io/afercia/pen/WmXqNy

Comment: @Maria-Elena Thank you very much!! That helped me a lot to figure out how these Admin layouts work. I think now I can try to implement something out myself!!

Comment: you are welcome, just mark it as a useful tag, please